# Use Regex to remove everything after image MEM type

Tags: regex, yahoo-pipes

Am garbing news from out sources, and most of the images are linked to the original source today.
My problem, some of the images source link look like this:

```
<img src="http://www.el-balad.com/upload/photo/news/78/1/360x232o/319.jpg?q=1" width="360"/>
```

How to use **regex in yahoo pipe** to make this link to look like this?

```
<img src="http://www.el-balad.com/upload/photo/news/78/1/360x232o/319.jpg"/>
```

The thing I need to change is:

```
.jpg?q=1&w=360&h=150&zc=1
```

To

```
.jpg
```

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: replace `\?.*` with nothing

Comment: @thefourthey am using regex in yahoo pipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use replacing :

replace `\?.*` by `\"`

If you want to select on the img src link

You can use the following code :

```
  (?<=img src=)[^ ]*\"
```

then you can replace `\?.*` by `\"`

**[Refer](http://regex101.com/r/cP5cU2)**

Comment: awesome, its working fine :) Thank you so much for the great support.